# country of origin vs origin country

Tags: difference, word-order

Is there any difference between "country of origin" and "origin country" ? Example:

It says "Made in Mexico". I wonder if that is the real country of origin / origin country .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more usual to say "country of origin". A Google [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=country+of+origin%2Corigin+country&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccountry%20of%20origin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corigin%20country%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccountry%20of%20origin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corigin%20country%3B%2Cc0) on that and "origin country" gives this graph, supporting my claim.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no semantic difference between "country of origin" and "origin country"
(Although ["country of origin" is certainly the popular term](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/223233/89910))

However, when it comes to saying things like *Made in Mexico* it could be a bit more ambiguous

It might actually only be assembled or packaged in Mexico

I bought some furniture purportedly *Made in the UK* a few years back
 
(that wasn't the reason I bought it, but it was slapped all over the catalogue pages).

When it shipped all the boxes were marked *Vietnam*. It turns out that it was only the design for the furniture that was British - the wood, labour, etc were all sourced/processed in Vietnam.

Comment: Could you please also mention in the answer if both expressions are equally usual?

Comment: See the [answer by Weather Vane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/223233/89910) for ngram usage stats (country of origin is more popular)